# Unable to update dimension relationship of cube (SSAS)

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, cube, dimension

Sorry if this question is just too basic.

I edit an ssas cube in Visual Studio, and in the tab "Dimension usage", I would like to add a dimension relationship of type "Regular" between a dimension and a measure group.

The dialog displays a warning as shown in the picture and it is not possible to add the relationship (the measure group select is empty). Which wizard is meant by the warning message?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that the measure group was linked from another cube and could not be edited. It was necessary to remove and recreate the measure group altogether.